# how to use panels on custome front page

Tags: theming, panels

I have created a custom page in Drupal 6 and named it page-node-1.tpl.php.
I want to create a panel drag and drop on this page. But when I create a panel it will assign a different name to the panel page. How can I create a panel page for my page-node-1.tpl.php?

I'm new to Drupal, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to set a page using Panels (I'm assuming Panels 3) in Drupal would be to go to the Panels interface and click "Add custom page". You can give that page any path you want such as /home - the path doesn't actually matter. Then, from the admin options: Administer -> Site Configuration -> Site information you can change your default front page. Input the path that you used when creating your new panel.

This will give you a new custom panels page that will show up as the default front page at www.yoursite.com

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR_dR8hXiDs) will walk you through the process step by step.

Comment: Thanks, how can i add my own CSS to this newly created panels